# in python/pandas, how to add lead vaue and filter the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In python/pandas, 1) How to add new variable  (the `lead_value` as image) ?  2) How to filter the dataframe which `type` include ":" ?

```
import pandas as pd
ori_df=pd.DataFrame()
ori_df=pd.DataFrame([['a','1'],['w:','z'],['t','6'],['f:','z'],['a','2']],
                    columns=['type','value']
                    )
```

[image]

Comment: how do you define the "lead value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

ori_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a','1'],['w:','z'],['t','6'],['f:','z'],['a','2']],
    columns=['type','value']
)

ori_df['lead_value'] = ori_df['value'].shift(-1).fillna(0)

ori_df_filtered = ori_df[ori_df['type'].apply(lambda t: ':' in t)]
print(ori_df_filtered)
```

prints

| index | type | value | lead_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | w: | z | 6 |
| 3 | f: | z | 2 |

Comment: lambda t: ':' in t  , the object variable  stand for variable 'type ' ?   thanks

Comment: yes that was the idea